# How to move column to next row if my 1st row has 5 div box

Tags: html, css

> Hello guys can anyone help me here, I've tried using display flex.
> However, the 6th box is overlapping I want my 6-10 Box stay on the 2nd
> row and if I add the 11th box it should start on the 3rd row can
> anyone help me with how can I accomplish it? Currently, it's working
> however my style is overlapping.

```css
.question-list-w {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 500px;
}

.question-list-w .horizontal-card {
    flex: 0 0 85px;
}
.horizontal-card {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-list-w">
<div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div><div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div><div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div><div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div><div class="horizontal-card">
    <div class="horizontal-card-icon"></div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-text">survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing traset sheets cont</div>
    <div class="horizontal-card-btn">
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-show-question" type="button" question-number="1">Show</button>
        <button class="horizontal-card-btn btn-start-question" question-number="1">Start</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
}

.flex>.item {
  width: calc(20% - (40px / 5));
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="item"> 1 </div>
  <div class="item"> 2 </div>
  <div class="item"> 3 </div>
  <div class="item"> 4 </div>
  <div class="item"> 5 </div>
  <div class="item"> 6 </div>
  <div class="item"> 7 </div>
  <div class="item"> 8 </div>
  <div class="item"> 9 </div>
  <div class="item"> 10 </div>
  <div class="item"> 11 </div>
  <div class="item"> 12 </div>
</div>
```

Make sure add flex-wrap to wrap and set flex child width dimention;

Comment: Hi Taurus thanks for this idea however I want my question start from top to bottom # 2 should place on number 6

Comment: then below #6 it should be 3 4 5 then the 6 will move to the next row or something like that

Comment: Sorry i don't understand what are mean. If i'm corrent what you want is for each row only five box right

Answer (score 0):

Use *percentage* instead of *px* on the flex-basis so that it won't overflow. It will only take height of available spaces.

```css
.question-list-w {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    height: 500px;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 17%;  /*grow | shrink | basis */
}
.card {
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="question-list-w">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card">2</div>
  <div class="card">3</div>
  <div class="card">4</div>
  <div class="card">5</div>
  <div class="card">6</div>
  <div class="card">7</div>
  <div class="card">8</div>
  <div class="card">9</div>
  <div class="card">10</div>
  <div class="card">11</div>
</div>
```